# how to generate postman collection for all the APIs in asp.net web api application?

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api, postman

We have REST APIs build on Asp.Net Web Api application. I'm looking for a tool or a way, that generates Postman collection for all the APIs from the application. As my application has numerous APIs call, it's difficult to manually add postman request one by one.

Please suggest any tools that do for us this.

Answer (score 3):

You can add [Swagger](http://swagger.io/) to your Web API project, which can give you a JSON representation of your APIs. This is available through NuGet. Then you can simply [import](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/importing_swagger) that JSON using Postman.

Answer (score 0):

I also found another way of generating postman collection by installing NuGet package "Postman.WebApi.HelpDocumentation" which works awesome. Then we can import this postman collection in JSON format by specifying the link to the API route which generates the collection; API is added by NuGet package.